# Почему у объекта View можно получить id?

Tags: android, kotlin

Иногда нам нужно View,когда мы составляем список из наших View(допустим кнопки) ,а затем проходим циклом for с вот этой функцией.

```
   when (view.id) {

       // Boxes using Color class colors for background
       R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
       R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

       // Boxes using Android color resources for background
       R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
       R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
       R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)

       else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
   }
}
```

Вопрос таков.Чем созданные при помощи listOf объекты отличаются от вот такого.И если мы пользуемся в основном первым(тоесть обращению к R),либо DataBinding,какая необходимость методов и создания экземпляров типа View,помимо того,что я описал выше

```
val button : Button =  findViewById(R.id.button0)

val numButtons : List<View> =
            listOf(button0,button1,button2,button3,
                button4,button5,button6,button7,
                button8,button9,button_ok,button_del)
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос - попробуйте как-то переформулировать или описать подробнее (чтобы редактировать вопрос нажмите кнопку [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1028657/edit)). Класс `R` ничего ни с чем не связывает - он только содержит константы-идентификаторы, которые мы используем для поиска вью и ресурсов.

Comment: Есть `View.getId()`. Например для обработки клика.

Comment: Поправил,простите за неточность

Comment: listOf() не создает никаких обьектов, кроме самого immutable обьекта списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам никто не мешает по старинке искать свои элементы интерфейса по id

```
val button : Button =  findViewById(R.id.button0)
```

В таком случае лучше отключить плагин `Android Extensions`, который делает эту работу за вас.  Чтобы не замедлял компиляцию и не генерил ненужный код.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Но не думаю, что это правильно отказываться от удобной вещи, которая облегчает вам жизнь.

Т.е. это `Android Extensions` генерит вам прямой доступ к вашим кнопкам `button0,button1,button2,...`, но никак не `listOf()` метод.

Он им генерит те же имена, как их `id`. Но это именно обьекты, не стоит их путать с примитивами из `R.id.*`.

Comment: Тоесть Android Extensions создает объекты с теми же именами и id,позволяет менять исходный xml.Отсюда вопрос.Можно ли полностью перейти к созданию объектов при помощи этого инструмента и за редким исключением обращаться через R? И в чем будет разница между ними?

Comment: Никакой разницы. Это одни и те же обьекты, потому что их создает система когда строит UI по XML-разметке. Android Extensions генерит код, который при первом обращении этот обьект ищет и кеширует для последующих. Это по сути эквивалентно тому как вы ищете по id и сохраняете в поле класса.

Answer (score 0):

`R` - это специальный класс, в котором содержатся все идентификаторы ресурсов и они целого типа `int`

Java - как известно, на всякий случай напоминаю, язык с жесткой типизацией, то есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы придумаете свой язык, в котором это возможно - то пожалуйста (подсказка - есть такие языки программирования), но не в Java